# Bigcommerce Api Python Basic Auth

Tags: python, authentication, basic-authentication, bigcommerce

I am having trouble authenticating to my store through the Bigcommerce Api using Python 2.7 and the Bigcommerce 0.11.0 library.  The error is:

`bigcommerce.exception.ClientRequestException: 401 Unauthorized @ time: [{"status":401,"message":"No credentials were supplied in the request."}]`

this is the test script I was using with all the various ways I tried to implement the basic auth

```
    import bigcommerce

    #Private apps (Basic Auth)
    api = bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi(host='store-XXXXX.mybigcommerce.com', basic_auth=('user ID', 'API Token'))

    #Private apps (Basic Auth)
    api = bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi(host='store URL', basic_auth=('user ID', 'API TOKEN'))
```

And

```
    import bigcommerce.api
    from bigcommerce.connection import Connection, OAuthConnection
    from bigcommerce.resources import ApiResource

    api = bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi(host='Store URL', basic_auth=('user ID', 'API TOKEN'))
```

The first example exception throw up an error in the requests library because the SSL certificate does not match the sites name.  The next two give `401`.

I also found this script on Github from someone and what appears to be a test script and it results in the same error message

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import bigcommerce.api

    api = bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi(host='Store URL', basic_auth=('user ID', 'API TOKEN')

    print(repr(api.Time.all()))
```

I have also tried running various versions of `print api()` and it always result in an error: `'module' object is not callable`

I'm just looking for help with what I'm doing wrong.  A way to test what the api variable actually looks like, or a way to do it without the bigcommerce library any insight would be great.  I never thought I'd be stumbling this close to the start line.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a step back and playing with the requests library directly, I figured I am using an older template from bigcommerce (3 years) and it only supports basic auth and maybe only delivers xml results. (That's what it defaulted to I haven't tried pulling json)

I've been able to connect using the requests library.  I am assuming that the bigcommerce library was not written to support such older stores.  If you find yourself in this situation and have an older site I can help you if you get stuck and are using python. just message me